# Visual studio 2012: Run web performance on build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, build, performance-testing

I´m new to Visual Studio and this might be very easy to do but i've been researching for almost a week now and haven't got any results.

The thing is i'm trying to do some QA on a web project in visual studio 2010 that is under a TFS. I've recorded and coded some of my tests but i need this tests to run when there is a new check in by any of the developers.

I've read some of the How To's from MSDN but this step by step walkthroughs are not specific enough for the web performance test.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please show us some code that you've tried, and the specific problems that you've encountered with that code. Read our FAQ for what makes a good question, it will help you get better answers: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you case you need to edit the build definition to include Build Verification Tests (BVTs) :   theses tests can do check post build and also post deploy.

Web Performance Test, Load Test, Coded UI Test ... it's quite the same for TFS : some code to run to check something.

The good starting point is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182465.aspx).